# How can I avoid TaskCanceledException by RemoteNavigationManager

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server app and every couple of minutes I get the following in my logs:

```
Error 12:09:54 [] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager - Navigation failed when changing the location to https://louishowe-dev.azurewebsites.net/Identity/Account/Login TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<NavigateToCore>g__PerformNavigationAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
Error 12:09:54 [] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost - Unhandled exception in circuit 'GdWjUPhwt9bdljJjyKo0M-eVaVKtacUkhqCtNuwOg-s'. TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<NavigateToCore>g__PerformNavigationAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
```

The program continues to run fine and the user sees no issue. But exceptions are generally bad news. What's going on here and how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in ASP.NET Core, but it seems that it's not solved yet - although it is marked as solved. You could find the existing issue here: [aspnetcore Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45267)